# How Python actually store and call functions on a lower-level?

Tags: python, function, oop, architecture

Everything in Python is an object, even a function is an object and in turn, they are first-class functions. Moreover, it allows techniques like Monkey Patching.

But, internally at the lower-level how does Python stores a function and eventually calls it?

Answer (score 0):

At the low level, callables are called by a number of C functions described in [`call.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a5552f023e1d8cbafee1e51d316cc581deb2295f/Objects/call.c) (depending on the type of callable object and what arguments are passed).

Functions (A particular kind of callable) are stored as python function objects, which can be found as `types.FunctionType`.